# How to marry 2 slightly varying data sets into one workable file

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hopefully I’m thinking about this logically….
How does one match up two different data sets but yet similar into one workable file.  For example, I have a master data set list out a hospital name, address, city and state.  I have another data set that has that has the hospital name, address, city, state and sales information.  I would like to marry both of them up but can’t due to varying nuances between both sets….For example:

```
     **Data Set 1**                     **Data Set 2 (with Sales info)**
```

Childrens Hospital of Baltimore                 Children’s Hosp of Baltimore
123 Baltimore Ave                       123 Baltimore Avenue
Baltimore, MD 12345                     Baltimore, MD 12345

These are essentially the same hospital but with slightly varying information.
Does anybody know of a way to get over this task.

Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED.

Comment: You don't indicate how big the data sets are.  Often in situations where the data is slightly different but both are technically correct and it varies record by record as to which data set has the one that is better, it is easier to do it manually than to try to write rules to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for this. It will read in two tables and return the best match (or matches), along with confidence and similarity scores.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

With typical data sets, you can set high and low boundaries based on the Confidence score (e.g. accept any match over 0.9, reject any match under 0.5), which leaves you with a smaller set of match candidates to review manually.